# Loading a 2nd UIScrollView at a specific index and displaying the result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a ContentViewController which contains a scrollView.

The scrollView shows 27 selectable items across 3 pages (9 items per page). This works fine.

When the user taps one of the items, I rebuild the scroll view's array to contain all 27 items across 27 pages, with 1 item per page (using a different view controller to display it). So when you select an item, you get a detail view.

However, regardless of which item the user selects, the second scroll view loads blank. According to the page control, the scrollview is in the right place, but nothing appears. It's not until I scroll the view that an item appears but it resets the index to the start of the list.

Sorry about the horrible amount of code, but perhaps this will help illustrate what's going wrong.

Many thanks for any advice.

```
- (void)objectSelected: (SelectableObject *)objectSelected {

detailView = TRUE;
self.selectedObject = objectSelected;

[self drawScrollingView];
```

}

```
- (void)drawScrollingView {

//Clear out any previous views
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

//Set the background and other interface elements
if (detailView) {
    self.background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectB.png"];
    self.nameField.hidden = FALSE;
    pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 380, pageControl.frame.size.width, pageControl.frame.size.height);
    numberPages = [self.contentList count];
}
else {
    self.background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectA1.png"];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
     //Determine the number of pages
    int items = [self.contentList count];
    numberPages = items/9;
    if (items % 9 != 0)
        numberPages++; 
}

// view controllers are created lazily
// in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < numberPages; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
self.viewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];

// a page is the width of the scroll view
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * numberPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

pageControl.numberOfPages = numberPages;
pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = TRUE;

if (!detailView) 
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
else
    pageControl.currentPage = self.selectedObject.number;

// pages are created on demand
// load the visible page
// load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageControl.currentPage-1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageControl.currentPage];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:pageControl.currentPage+1];
```

}

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= numberPages)
    return;

NSLog(@"PAGE: %i", page);

if (!detailView) {
    //Get the subset of objects, depending on the page, and pass it to the controller
    //There are 9 objects per page, so page 0 covers 0-8, page 1 covers 9-17, 2 18-26. 
    //However, there may not be a total of 9
    int startIndex = page*9;
    int length = 9;
    int total = [self.contentList count];
    if (startIndex+length > total)
        length = total-startIndex;

    NSRange theRange;
    theRange.location = startIndex;
    theRange.length = length;
    NSArray *selectionSubset = [self.contentList subarrayWithRange:theRange];

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    SelectionScreenViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[SelectionScreenViewController alloc] initWithSet:selectionSubset];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }
    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"DETAIL VIEW");
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    SelectionDetailViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"controller is NULL");
        controller = [[SelectionDetailViewController alloc] initWithObject:[self.contentList objectAtIndex:page]];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }
    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        NSLog(@"controller superview is NIL");
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
// We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
// which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
// the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
if (pageControlUsed) {
    // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
    return;
}

// Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
NSLog(@"contentOffset: %g", scrollView.contentOffset);

int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
if (detailView) { //some other formula here to determine page???

}


pageControl.currentPage = page;

// Set the name
self.selectedObject = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];
self.nameField.text = self.selectedObject.name;

NSLog(@"NAME: %@", [[self.contentList objectAtIndex:page] name]);
NSLog(@"ScrollViewDidScrool page: %i", page);

// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to set contentOffset to your scroll view.

At the time of creating scroll view add below line.

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * self.selectedObject.number, scrollView.frame.origin.y);
```

Comment: Wow, worked like a dream. I figured I needed to do something with the contentOffset but just couldn't figure it out. Thank you!!!